# Android Keep Activity in Background

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a multiple activity app - MainActivity, CpuActivity, etc. My CpuActivity has fragments that have `savedInstanceState`. Whenever I press back or navigate up to the MainActivity the CpuActivity is killed and the `savedInstanceState` is lost. Is it possible to keep the saved data/activity in the background or do I need to use some kind of temporary storage (e.g. SharedPreferences)?

The data should only be stored until the whole app is killed, so is there any system better than SharedPreferences?

Comment: As far as I know you are not allowed to have apps running in the background without the system to finish your activities when memory is needed. So I suggest you have a look at some sort of storage for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to store the data in your application instance. To do that you have to specify an Application implementation in the manifest (the android:name attribute in the application tag). You can get the application using the [getApplication() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29).