# Android: How to get back to the Calling Activity without using finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

I call an activity called Activity1 from an Activity called MainActivity using the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

So, when the control comes to Activity1. The normal activity lifecycle is started. i.e onCreate() is called and so on.

when i click the back button when the control is in Activity1. The finish method is called, which in turn calls the onDestroy() and now the control is back with the MainActivity screen.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed()");
        finish();
    }
```

The next time i call Activity1. The onCreate is called again as i called the onDestroy (when i pressed the back button) from the previous call.

Question:
    1. is there a way to pass control back to the MainActivity when the back button is pressed without having to call the "finish()" method?
    2. problem with calling finish, every time i call Activity1 from MainActivity, A new instance of Activity1 is created. that is  the lifecycle again starts from onCreate().. 
    i do not want this to happen as this is has become a major performance issue.

The main point i'm looking for is whether i can start the activity1 from the resume state rather than oncreate, when i call it after the first time.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this but: When you first start Activity1, can't you instantiate it with the activity context for Main Activity and use that to resume Main Activity without destroying and recreating it?

Comment: Check this thread , it the same as yours , hope it helps 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789648/android-keep-activity-in-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need to call the "finish()" method on onBackPressed. Android does that for you when you press the back button. The onBackPressed is used to last minuet tidy up (save stuff to sharepreferences, etc).

Android default behaviour is to call onCreate whenever a new activity is place on the screen. You cannot call a new Intent without this to happen.

I'm not sure why this is performance issue for you. Can you go in a little more detail what activity1 is doing? Are you doing heavy network communication? Is it possible you can cache the store results?

Comment: Hi Jerad, I load a WebView, data from a network connection  in Activity1. So, everytime i go to Activity1 from MainActivity. i do not want to reload the webview and also the data from a network.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html

Comment: Scott: thanks for the link. At this time, the main point im looking is whether i can call the activity the second time around from the resumed state rather than the oncreate state

Answer (score 0):

in Actitity1 you define your WebView as:

```
private static WebView webView = null;
```

in `onCreate()` you only create it if it's null:

```
if(webView == null){
  //create webview and load from network
}
```

Use this approach wisely as it may easly lead to memory leaks if you point to objects in other activities, or objects that may be kept alive (runnables, messages, etc.)

Comment: Hi Luis, everytime the Activity1 starts, The webview will be inititalized to null as oncreate is called again. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: The webview should be global, defined outside the oncreate(). It will be initialized just once with null, when you start your application (not with activity1 start). When the activity1 starts for the first time, the variable is already initialized with null. When it starts for the second time, the variable will have the value remaining from the first execution.